# How to wait for somthing to happen without freezing the UI

Tags: vb.net, web-controls, awesomium

I want my app to wait until web browser loads completely so i can use the `DocumentCompleted` event, but the problem is that i am using awesmoium webkit and the `LoadingFrameComplete` event does not fire. when iam searching on google like iam on google and searched 'VB.NET' it is not fired so i want to pause `address changed` event and wait until web control loads and the code that i set on `LoadingFrameComplete` event  like

```
public Sub webcontrol_addresschanged(sender As Object, e As Awesomium.Core.UrlEventArgs)
//WAIT UNTIL WEB CONTROL LOADS
//DO Something"
End sub
```

I tried using 'do until' loop but it freeze gui and the web control isn't navigating.

Comment: You could avoid the freezing using Async event handler with Await operation within it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score -1):

Create a Module, Name it anything (except Delay)

Copy-Paste These Codes in Module

Codes :

```
Sub Delay(ByVal dblSecs As Double)
    Const OneSec As Double = 1.0# / (1440.0# * 60.0#)
    Dim dblWaitTil As Date
    Now.AddSeconds(OneSec)
    dblWaitTil = Now.AddSeconds(OneSec).AddSeconds(dblSecs)
    Do Until Now > dblWaitTil
        Application.DoEvents() ' Allow windows message to be processed
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now, Save it return to your form's codes

Type This

```
public Sub webcontrol_addresschanged(sender As Object, e As    Awesomium.Core.UrlEventArgs)
Delay(2) 'Delay(x) means x seconds of delay before executing next command without freezing UI
//DO Something"
End sub
```